# How to filter array from selected tableviewcell in swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I am quite puzzled on how will I construct my codes regarding on how I will filter the selected array from a `tableviewcell`. The `JSON` below is the content of the tableview which displays like [image: this]

```
[
    {
    "hospitalNumber": "00000001",
    "patientName": "Test Patient",
    "totalAmount": 1111.3
    },
    {
    "hospitalNumber": "00000002",
    "patientName": "Test Patient 2",
    "totalAmount": 1312
    },
    {
    "hospitalNumber": "00000003",
    "patientName": "Test Patient 3",
    "totalAmount": 475
    }
]
```

The problem is how can I display the selected `hospitalNumber` and `patientName` in the next `View Controller`, which will display like [image: this]

This is what my `PaymentDetailsViewController' have:

```
 var patientList: [Patient]! {
    didSet {
        latestCreditedAmountTableView.reloadData()
    }
}

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

  getPatientList()

 }
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
      if segue.identifier == "showPatientPaymentDetailsVC" {
        if let patientPaymentDetailsVC = segue.destination as? PatientPaymentDetailsViewController {
            patientPaymentDetailsVC.isBrowseAll = self.isBrowseAll

            if !isBrowseAll {
                patientPaymentDetailsVC.patientPayoutDetails = self.selectedPatientPayment
                patientPaymentDetailsVC.currentRemittance = self.currentRemittance
                patientPaymentDetailsVC.doctorNumber = self.doctorNumber

            }
        }
    }
}


func getPatientList() {
    SVProgressHUD.setDefaultMaskType(.black)
    SVProgressHUD.show(withStatus: "Retrieving Patient List")

    APIService.PatientList.getPatientList(doctorNumber: doctorNumber, periodId: currentRemittance.periodId) { (patientListArray, error) in
        guard let patientListPerPayout = patientListArray, error == nil else {
            if let networkError = error {
                switch networkError {
                case .noRecordFound:
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "No Record Found", message: "You don't have current payment remittance", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                case .noNetwork:
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "No Network", message: "\(networkError.rawValue)", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                default:
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "There is something went wrong. Please try again", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
            return
        }

        self.patientList = patientListPerPayout
        self.latestCreditedAmountTableView.reloadData()
        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        return

    }
}

**getPerPatientPAyoutDetails(from: String) function**

func getPerPatientPayoutDetails(from: String) {
    SVProgressHUD.setDefaultMaskType(.black)
    SVProgressHUD.showInfo(withStatus: "Retrieving Patient Details")

    APIService.PatientList.getPatientDetailsPerPayout(periodId: currentRemittance.periodId, doctorNumber: doctorNumber, parameterName: .selectedByHospitalNumber, hospitalNumber: from) { (patientPayout, error) in

        guard let patientPerPayoutDetails = patientPayout, error == nil else {
            if let networkError = error {
                switch networkError {
                case .noRecordFound:
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "No Record Found", message: "You don't have current payment remittance", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
                case .noNetwork:
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "No Network", message: "\(networkError.rawValue)", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                default:
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "There is something went wrong. Please try again", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
            return
        }
        self.selectedPatientPayment = patientPerPayoutDetails
        print(self.selectedPatientPayment)

        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        return
    }
}
```

Base on the `gePatientList()` function, it will just pull the full list of the patients. I don't know how I will pass the data of the selected patient to another VC. Hope you can help me. Thank you so much.

**Codes that might help to understand the flow of my codes**

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0: break
    case 1: let selectedpatient = patientList[indexPath.row].hospitalNumber
    print(selectedpatient!)
    self.isBrowseAll = false
    getPerPatientPayoutDetails(from: selectedpatient!)
    default: break
    }
}
```

Below is the another `View Controller` that will display the `patientName` and `hospitalNumber`

**PatientPaymentDetailsVC**

```
class PatientPaymentDetailsViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var patientProcedureTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var hospitalNumberLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var patientNameLabel: UILabel!

var currentRemittance: CurrentRemittance!
var doctorNumber: String!
var isBrowseAll: Bool!
var patientList: [Patient]!

var patientPayoutDetails: [PatientPayoutDetails]!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupPatientInfo()

 }

 //MARK: FUNCTION

 func setupPatientInfo() {
    self.patientNameLabel.text = patient.patientName
    self.hospitalNumberLabel.text = patient.hospitalNumber
}
```

The pulled data under the `getPerPatientPayoutDetails` function from the `didselect` will be displayed in `PatientPaymentDetailsVC`. Below is the output, as you can I see I can pull the data under `getPerPatientPayoutDetails` but the `patientName` and `hospitalNumber` does not display the data. [image]

Comment: It's a little difficult to tell as to which part you're facing problem with. If I understand correctly, you just need to get the selected cell in your `override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {` function, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all don't get the data from the table view cell, get it from the data source

- Connect the segue to the **cell**.
- Delete the entire method `didSelectRowAt`
- When `prepare(for segue` is called the `sender` parameter is the `cell`.
- Get the index path from the cell and get the patient at that index path.
- Rather than passing multiple parameters declare a `var patient : Patient!` property in the destination controller and hand over the `patient` instance.

---

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard segue.identifier == "showPatientPaymentDetailsVC",
      let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell,
      let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else { return }

    let patient = patientList[indexPath.row]
    getPerPatientPayoutDetails(from: patient.hospitalNumber)

    let patientPaymentDetailsVC = segue.destination as! PatientPaymentDetailsViewController
    patientPaymentDetailsVC.patient = patient
    patientPaymentDetailsVC.patientPayoutDetails = self.selectedPatientPayment
    patientPaymentDetailsVC.currentRemittance = self.currentRemittance
    patientPaymentDetailsVC.doctorNumber = self.doctorNumber
}
```

---

```
class PatientPaymentDetailsViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var patientProcedureTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var hospitalNumberLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var patientNameLabel: UILabel!

var currentRemittance: CurrentRemittance!
var doctorNumber = ""
var isBrowseAll = false
var patient : Patient!

var patientPayoutDetails: [PatientPayoutDetails]!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupPatientInfo()

 }

 //MARK: FUNCTION

 func setupPatientInfo() {
    self.patientNameLabel.text = patient.patientName
    self.hospitalNumberLabel.text = patient.hospitalNumber
}
```

Side note:

Don't declare `patientList` as implicit unwrapped optional, declare it as non-optional empty array

```
var patientList : [Patient]()
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggested answer, just what to ask, how can I include those commented out part together with your answer? Thank you

Comment: I commented it out because there is no information what those lines are supposed to do.

Comment: sorry if my codes are lacking but I already added codes that might help to fully understand it. If you don't mind, you may check it out. Thank you so much.

Comment: There is still some ambiguity but I updated the answer

Comment: Hi again, still not working and the `patientProcedureTableView`  inside `PatientPaymentDetailsViewController` (2nd view controller) become empty

Comment: Sorry, as I said the information is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Use `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` method by conforming to `UITableViewDelegate`.
Get the selected patient as displayed below:

```
selectedPatient = tableView[indexpath.row] as! [String:Any]
```

As per your edited question, try this:

```
let patient = patientList[indexPath.row] as! Patient
```